# Terraform output: Error: module "rds": "monitoring_role_arn" is not a valid argument

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I have added the following in my tf code:

```
module "rds" "app" {
  source = "git@github.com:*****/aws-terraform-rds.git"

  name                   = "${var.rds_name_app}"
  engine                 = "${var.rds_engine_app}"
  engine_version         = "${var.rds_engine_version_app}"
  family                 = "${var.rds_family_app}"
  instance_class         = "${var.rds_instance_class_app}"

  password                   = "${random_string.rds_password.result}"
  port                       = "${var.rds_port_app}"
  security_groups            = ["${aws_security_group.rds_app.id}"]
  subnets                    = ["${module.vpc.public_subnets}"]
  auto_minor_version_upgrade = "${var.rds_auto_minor_version_upgrade_app}"
  backup_retention_period    = "${var.rds_backup_retention_period_app}"
  backup_window              = "${var.rds_backup_window_app}"
  maintenance_window         = "${var.rds_maintenance_window_app}"
  environment                = "${var.environment}"
  kms_key_id                 = "${aws_kms_key.rds.arn}"
  multi_az                   = "${var.rds_multi_az_app}"
  notification_topic         = "${var.rds_notification_topic_app}"
  publicly_accessible        = "${var.rds_publicly_accessible_app}"
  storage_encrypted          = "${var.rds_storage_encrypted_app}"
  storage_size               = "${var.rds_storage_size_app}"
  storage_type               = "${var.rds_storage_type_app}"
  monitoring_interval        = "${var.rds_monitoring_interval_app}"
  monitoring_role_arn        = "${var.rds_monitoring_role_arn_app}"
  apply_immediately          = true
```

The variables are present in the variables.tf file.

When I run terraform plan it gives me the following error:

Error: module "rds": "monitoring_role_arn" is not a valid argument

I am not sure why I am getting this error since the "monitoring_role_arn" is a valid terraform argument.

Comment: From the `source` parameter I'm guessing you've made a private copy of the module - have you made any changes to it?

Comment: I have not made any changes to module itself. I am using a variable.tf file in the current repository where I am making all the changes.

Comment: Since I can't see your git repo, I need to ask: are you sure the module you have in that repo accepts a `monitoring_role_arn` argument?

Comment: hmm seems like that is the issue. I will try adding a a variable in the source repo and run it again. Thank you!

Comment: If the source repo doesn't already accept that argument, then just adding it as a variable isn't going to make it use it. It sounds like you either have the wrong module code in your repo, or you are working from a very old version of the module (I think that argument was added ~3 years ago)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They key term in the error message is `module`:

`Error: module "rds": "monitoring_role_arn" is not a valid argument`

This consistently means that a module you're using, rather than an AWS resource, is missing a specific variable that you're trying to pass to it, in its `variables.tf`.

This is regardless of any resource used inside the module. Even if you'd delete all resources from the module (e.g. RDS), you'd get the same error.